# Does std::vector.clear() do delete (free memory) on each element?

Tags: c++, std

Consider this code:

```
#include <vector>

void Example()
{
    std::vector<TCHAR*> list;
    TCHAR* pLine = new TCHAR[20];
    list.push_back(pLine);
    list.clear();    // is delete called here?
    // is delete pLine; necessary?
}
```

Does `list.clear()` call `delete` on each element? I.e. do I have to free the memory before / after `list.clear()`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No (you need to do the delete yourself at the end as you suggest in your example as the destruction of the bald pointer doesnt do anything). But you can use a boost [or other RAII-based idiom] smart pointer to make it Do The Right Thing (`auto_ptr` would not work correctly in a container as it has incompatible behaviour under copying etc.), but be sure you understand the pitfalls of such smart pointers before use. (As Benoit mentions, in this case, `basic_string` is what you're really looking for here.)

Having said that there's a need to understand the pitfalls of smart pointers, having them take care of the memory management implicitly so you dont have to do it explicitly is far less error-prone.

EDIT: Substantially revised to encompass the elements Benoit brought into his far more thorough answer, thanks to strong prodding from the Earwicker and James Matta - thanks for pushing me to do the due diligence on this!

Comment: auto_ptr cannot be used. auto_ptr breaks when used with STL containers.

Comment: You should edit the answer to remove the reference auto_ptr. It's not actually possible to use it in a container.

Comment: @JM Removing out of order comment from earlier, who do I think I am !

Answer (score 55):

`std::vector` does call the destructor of every element it contains when `clear()` is called.
In your particular case, it destroys the pointer but the objects remain.

Smart pointers are the right way to go, but be careful. `auto_ptr` cannot be used in std containers. `boost::scoped_ptr` can't either. `boost::shared_ptr` can, but it won't work in your case because you don't have a pointer to an object, you are actually using an array. So the solution to your problem is to use [`boost::shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm).

But I suggest you use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` instead, where you won't have to deal with memory management, while still getting the benefits of working with a string.

Comment: Good point, feel free to edit these details into my answer... (Me's slightly rusty in me C++ and am embarassed I didnt mention basic_string!)

Comment: When I comes to memory management, I am somewhat a control freak. I live in the land of embedded (mobile phones) development. It gives me the creeps to use partially managed API. The layer under UI is ANSI C.

Comment: What do you consider "partially managed" ? shared_array or basic_string ? Either way, i think it's pretty complete ! If you're into controlling memory management, i would not use std::vector in the first place. It might reserve memory without telling you !

Comment: @Benoit: Oh yeah, well I gave you 10 to head you towards the 3k!
@Ignas: Well worth exploring managed stuff and the RAI pattern in general (I've been exploring it in .NET for a few years, but even before that, I'd written my last delete/free many years before!)

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink : thanks but still a long way to go, i guess !

Comment: @Benoit: by "partially managed" I meant the whole system I am working on. What I am implementing right now (one piece of UI) is some 2% of the whole thing. Some 90% of the solution can never be managed.

Comment: @Benoit: I use std::vector just to cut some corners. I need some easy way to have a dynamically changing array without lots of effort. Any recommendations instead of std::vector?

Comment: Not really. If you want to make sure that std::vector does not reserve slots unless you ask for them, there might be compilation options for stlport that do that. Not sure though !

Comment: @Benoit: You're right, that'll teach me! [about not not reading the text of the answers before I comment] (Only visited this post as it was +1d yesterday)

Answer (score 9):

Here's one way that you can tell that it doesn't - try it on a class that's not fully defined:

```
#include <vector>
class NotDefined;

void clearVector( std::vector<NotDefined*>& clearme )
{
    clearme.clear();    // is delete called here?
}
```

If this snippet compiles, then it can't be calling the destructor, because the destructor isn't defined.

Comment: I think your answer might be true for this specific case but not in general I thought of `SFINAE` or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible they would allow to call destructor if defined.

Answer (score 8):

Nope. It doesn't do that since there is no guarantee you are not using the pointer anywhere else. If it wasn't a pointer variable, it would free them (by calling the destructor)

Comment: @Ignas: How should std::vector know how to delete the pointer? It might have been allocated with new, with malloc or with any other memory allocation function (OS-Specific, hand-written), there's no way to tell from the type.

Answer (score 8):

You could just write a simple template function that does this for you:

```
template <class T>
void deleteInVector(vector<T*>* deleteme) {
    while(!deleteme->empty()) {
        delete deleteme->back();
        deleteme->pop_back();
    }

    delete deleteme;
}
```

Maybe something in here is bad practice but I don't think so. It looks okay to me though comments are always nice.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. If `list.push_back(pLine)` throws, the memory will still be leaked. The correct thing is to us `std::vector<TCHAR>` instead of `TCHAR*`.

Comment: This is a bad approach. Pointers everywhere make programs extremely slow. The critical way to write fast programs nowadays is to always use contiguous memory, and the best way is to use vector<T> directly, T not being a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to use the [Boost Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). Not specifically recommended here (again because you're using arrays instead of single objects, though `std::string` would take care of that), but it's a useful and little-known library that solves the problem stated in the title.