# Does Clear() method of STL containers calls delete on heap objects?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does std::vector.clear() do delete (free memory) on each element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594089/does-stdvector-clear-do-delete-free-memory-on-each-element)

I have a map where second elements are heap allocated.

Shall I explicitly call `delete` while iterating or does method `erase()` and `clear()` do that for me?

Here is my destructor which erases second element that are allocated with `new`

```
        ~Event()
        {
            auto iter = mapper.begin();
            while (iter != mapper.end())
            {                   
                mapper.erase(iter++); // heap object
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I have a map where second elements are heap allocated". Possibly you mean you have a map where the second (value) elements are pointers, which point to something allocated by you from the heap? If a container has a pointer type for its elements, then the elements are the pointers. Anything that they may or may not point to isn't part of the container, and certainly isn't an element of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to explicitly call `delete` on each `new` element.
Standard Library containers do not take ownership of the dynamic memory allocated to pointers.

You should use Smart pointers as container elements if you need automatic cleanup.

Comment: How do you manage to find the ansewr so quick? bookmarks maybe?

Comment: @codekiddy It's called _knowing your stuff_, it's what craftsmen do.

Comment: @codekiddy: every decent C++ programmer know this without bookmarks or searching....

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't. You have to call `delete` yourself (or use smart pointers).

Comment: I heard smart pointers are bad with STL containers, so I'll use delete :(

Comment: @codekiddy It's the old `std::auto_ptr` which was troublesome. The new `std::shared_ptr` et al are fine.