# C++ freezes on testing whether a member variable equals NULL

Tags: c++, binary-tree, eclipse-cdt, tree-traversal, huffman-code

I created a program which, so far, creates a binary tree of nodes for a Huffman coding program. For some reason, when the debugger gets to the point where it tests if the two children equal Null or not (so there an actual character on the tree and not just a parent), the program freezes. Codes is an array of the codes for each object comprising of Code structs which have two member variables.

```
void Huff::traverse(Node* root, vector<Code>* code, string code_base){
    if(root->childL == NULL && root->childR == NULL){ //stops here
        Code c;
        c.content = root->litteral;
        c.symbol = code_base;
        code->push_back(c);
    }else{
        if (root->childL != NULL)
            traverse(root->childL, code, code_base + '0');
        if (root->childR != NULL)
            traverse(root->childR, code, code_base + '1');
    }
}
```

The function which calls this one is (it's called towards the end):

```
vector<Code>* Huff::compress(){
    //-------GETTING WEIGHTS/FREQUENCIES------
    vector<Node *>* nodes = new vector<Node*>; // Vector of nodes for later use
    map<char, int>* freq = new map<char, int>; //  Map to find weight of nodes
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++)
        (*freq)[content[i]]++; 
    CopyTo copyto(nodes); //sets vector<Node*> to copy to 
    for_each(freq->begin(), freq->end(), copyto); // Copies 
    delete freq;
    vector<Node *>::iterator beg = nodes->begin();

    //-------SETTING UP TO BUILD TREE------
    if(nodes->size() % 2 == 1){ //makes sure there are an even number of nodes
        Node* fill = new Node;
        fill->set_node(0, '*', NULL, NULL);
        nodes->push_back(fill);
    }
    huff_sort(nodes); // sort nodes by weight

    //-------BUILDING TREE------
    while(nodes->size() != 1){ //Sorts nodes by weight and then removes two of them and replaces them with one
        int w= (**beg).weight + (**(beg+1)).weight;
        Node* p = new Node;
        p->set_node(w, '*', *nodes->begin(), *(nodes->begin()+1)); //making it the parent node of the two lowest nodes
        nodes->erase(nodes->begin(), nodes->begin()+2);
        unsigned int i = 0;
        while(w > (*nodes)[i]->weight && i <= nodes->size()){ //finds where to insert the parent node based on weight
            i++;
        }
        if(i > nodes->size()) //if it needs to be inserted at the end
            nodes->push_back(p);
        else
            nodes->insert(nodes->begin()+i, p);
        delete p;
    }

    //-------TRAVERSING TREE------
    Node* root = (*nodes)[0];
    delete nodes;
    vector<Code>* codes;
    traverse(root, codes , "");
    delete root;
    return codes;
}
```

Note: The while loop before the traverse tree block of code is where the tree is created

Comment: I see nothing about that line that would cause the program to freeze. I think more information is needed. Don't you have access to a debugger?

Comment: Is root valid?  I'd say probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say `delete nodes;` after you call `traverse`.  What you have right now makes `root` point to `NULL` before you call `traverse`.

Comment: But nodes is just a pointer to a vector of pointers to nodes. Wouldn't it just delete the vector and the pointers, but not the node itself?

Comment: No, because the node itself *is* a pointer and you're deleting what it points to.

Comment: Wait, so delete vector goes through and deletes all the pointers in vector nodes points too as well as the vector itself?

Comment: Thanks, but then there are two bugs in this code because even if I take out the delete nodes, the bug persists.

Comment: @JackRadcliffe no, deleting the vector doesn't `delete` the objects it contains! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594089/does-stdvector-clear-do-delete-free-memory-on-each-element

Comment: It seems as though I was mistaken.

Comment: @VincenzoPii Then this is really strange because when I go through the debugger again, right after "root = (*nodes)[0]" roots has all the correct values, then when it hits "delete nodes", all of those values go away.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `root` points to something (`if (root) ...`). This should help.