# Memory Leak on Pointer Change in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I defined these types

```
typedef double* DoublePointer;
typedef vector<DoublePointer> DoubleVector;
typedef vector<DoubleVector> DoubleMatrix;
```

where `DoubleMatrix` as you see its really a vector of vectors containing pointers to doubles. I have two questions regarding how C++ manages memory:

1. Say I have a `DoubleMatrix m` and call `m.clear()`. Will this free the memory of all the `DoubleVector`s and all the `DoublePointers`s inside them?
2. If I equal two pointers say `m[0][0] = m[1][1]`, will the memory space that `m[0][0]` was pointing to (e.g to a `2.0`) will be eventually freed? (Does this question even make sense?)

I hope I was clear enough. I am really programming in Cython but its all compiled down to C++; while I have some basic knowledge of C, these kind of details elude me.

Thanks.

Comment: this is not a 'C' question so suggest the 'C' tag be removed

Comment: You seem to be confused about vectors and arrays -- `vector[DoublePointer]` will not compile.  Perhaps you mean `std::vector<DoublePointer>`?  Or perhaps you meant to write `DoublePointer[MAX_SIZE]`.  Depends on whether you mean C or C++

Comment: Sorry @ChrisDodd, thats how you write it in Cython. I think the C++ code should be `vector<DoublePointer> DoubleVector`.

Answer (score 2):

To Answer your questions:

> Will this free the memory of all the DoubleVectors and all the
>   DoublePointerss inside them?

No (free the memory of DoubleVector)and No (free the memory of the DoublePointer):

- Vector is an special type of container which it's analogue to an array. When you "clear" it, you just invalidate all the positions, but you don't resize it, mantaining all the positions (marked as empty) in memory. The best option should be clear and after it resize(0);
- ̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶l̶e̶a̶r̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶e̶s̶t̶r̶u̶c̶t̶o̶r̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶a̶i̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶t̶e̶m̶s̶ The destructors are called, but for trivial pointers they do nothing and they dont free the pointed memory. Look comments, please. Thanks  @BenVoigt [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594089/does-stdvector-clear-do-delete-free-memory-on-each-element).

> If I equal two pointers say `m[0][0] = m[1][1]`, will the memory space
>   that `m[0][0]` was pointing to (e.g to a 2.0) will be eventually freed?
>   (Does this question even make sense?)

No, it doesn't frees. The question makes sense and usually people only point to the memory leak, but this kind of pointer assigments is the origin of many double free's: after the assignment `m[0][0]` and `m[1][1]` are pointing to the same memory segment in heap, if you do a for deleting all the pointers, you will free twice the memory segment pointed by `m[0][0]` and `m[1][1]`

Comment: This is not completely correct.  In particular, your second bullet is totally wrong.  The DoubleVector destructors will all run, which frees the buffers they hold (arrays of DoublePointers).  In turn the DoublePointer destructors will run, but they do nothing (raw pointers have trivial destructors, which do not free the pointed-to memory)  Finally, you are correct that the memory held by DoubleMatrix (space for the DoubleVector objects themselves, which is just the metadata) will as you revert to unused capacity rather than being deallocated.

Comment: @BenVoigt, you are right, I doen't look std::vector<>::clear reference. The object destructors are called.  Feel free to edit my anser. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks guys. So I take it I should iterate through all `DoublePointer` and call `free` on them to avoid a leak?

Comment: @CristianGarcia: If this is the only pointer to that data, then you'd better call a deallocation function before losing the pointer.  Could be `free` or `delete` or `HeapFree` or whatever matches the function used to allocate the memory in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want automatic garbage collection, you will need to use a smart pointer. A std::vector<> is just a container. In this case, it is a vector of ints because a pointer is an int (or size_t) value which is the memory location to the actual data. The pointer goes out of scope. It's just that int back there. However, the memory that you allocated stays! It's just like:

```
void memLeak()
{
    int* x = new int[1024];
    return;
}
```

In that case, you allocated 1024 ints, but you didn't deallocate them. That x, however, went out of scope and was destroyed with big meaty claws!
To fix this issue, use a smart pointer to do the GC for you!:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<double> > name;
```

I few weeks ago, I was experiencing a memory leak which was confusing because I was using a smart container. It turned out that the reason behind the leak was that the memory was not being deallocated. The pointers to that memory were going out of scope and delete[] or free() weren't being called!.

Please let me know if you don't understand something or want me to elaborate! :)

Comment: A pointer is not an int. It's a pointer. It indicates where another value may be found in memory.  The rest of your explanation is good though.

Comment: it's not an int. you're right. However, an int is a way to visualize the relationship.